# Remove Yasnippet from the menu bar

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

How to remove the YASnippet category from the Emacs menu bar?

Answer (score 2):

M-x customize-variable RET yas-use-menu

A value of nil should do the job

Comment: It obviously sounds like a correct answer (variable's description sounds reasonable as well: `Display a YASnippet menu in the menu bar`) but it just isn't working...

Comment: @vemv, hmmm, it seems like a bug in yas.  If I do `(setq-default yas-use-menu nil)` then `yas-global-mode` fails because `yas-reload-all` assumes a menu exists despite the customization.  My advice would be to report this bug to yas maintainer.

Answer (score 1):

Add these line after loading Yasnippet

```
(setq yas-use-menu nil)
(yas-reload-all)
```

Comment: So how about set this variable after yasnippet initial? You can try this code after your yasnippet has been loaded. 
`
(setq yas-use-menu nil)
(yas-reload-all)
`

Comment: I have edited the answer, please try that. It's working fine on my machine.

Comment: Still not working, unfortunately :( I tried it in the following sequence (among others): `(setq yas-use-menu nil) (require 'yasnippet)(yas-reload-all) (menu-bar-mode) (yas-global-mode 1)`

Comment: try this sequence :
(require 'yasnippet) 
(setq yas-use-menu nil)
(yas-reload-all)